# Pivot table formula field

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have the following situation which I cannot resolve.
Below is a sample of the data I have (org file is dynamic and contains more then 300K rows of data)

I'm trying to make make the pivot to count the number of unique PN.
You can see what I expect to get vs. what I'm getting!
*I have added a "Count" formula field but I'm aware that the grand total's formula is now also "count".

How do I achieve this to be part of the Pivot table?

ScreenShot:

[image]

Comment: Are you using currently using PowerPivot? The `Insert Calculated Field` isn't an option in a Pivot Table created by PowerPivot.

Comment: Nop, Just regular Pivot table...

Comment: I was confused, because of the tag you used. PowerPivot is very different